# Get Listbox SelectedValue in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a MainWindow that contains A listbox, and a ContentControl, each time you select something from the Listbox, the ContentControl will display something else.

```
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=SomeList, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />

  <ListBox  x:Name="SomeList" Margin="0 16 0 16" SelectedIndex="0"  SelectedValue="{Binding X}"            
                         ItemsSource="{Binding DemoItems}">
```

ViewModel:

```
 private string _X;
    public string X

    {
        get { return _X; }
        set
        {
            _X = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("X");
        }
    }
```

Trying to display X will result in the same thing:

> namespace.DemoItem

DemoItem.cs:

```
 public class DemoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _icon;
    private string _name;
    private object _content;
    private Thickness _marginRequirement;

    public DemoItem(object icon, string name, object content, Thickness margin,  IEnumerable<DocumentationLink> documentation)
    {
        _icon = icon;
        _name = name;
        Content = content;
        _marginRequirement = margin;

        Documentation = documentation;
    }
}
```

So how is it possible to only get the name?

Comment: You wish to display in ContentControl value of the _name field of selected DemoItem?

Comment: At this point, I only want to get the Value selected in Listbox but since I have multiple objects, I only wnat to get the Name, not icon, not thickness, nothing. Just the name.

Comment: Then @Clemens has an answer for you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data binding only works with public properties. So add a `Name` property

```
public class DemoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
}
```

Assuming that yous intention is to selected a DemoItem by its `Name`, you should also set the ListBox's `SelectedValuePath` in conjunction with `SelectedValue`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DemoItems}"
         SelectedValuePath="Name"
         SelectedValue="{Binding X}" />
```

Then simply display the selected item's Name like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding X}" />
```

Comment: I guess I made my question more complicated then It should be. My Listbox contain an icon, a string etc. I want to get the string (name) of any the selected item. That's all. I tried adding SelectedValuePath, but that's resulting in an empty MessageBox.

Comment: That's what you get here.

Comment: Worked, I appreciate it. The problem was that I had SelectedValuePath in lowercase (name instead of Name) :)